Fitting a curve with sin(atan)
I'm trying to fit a curve using the curve_fit from scipy, but I'm getting RuntimeError. I have an input data (x,y) and I'd like to fit it to an equation defined in the y_fit function. Does anyone know if there is a limitation with this type of function? Thank you.
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
        
x =  np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,15)

y = [-86.97572322743066, -89.53074407145257, -92.87263307518653,
       -97.35933273748071, -103.42406004626562, -110.56817865568372,
         -106.1393898655548, 0.0, 106.13938986555478,
           110.56817865568372,103.42406004626562, 97.35933273748071,
             92.87263307518657, 89.53074407145257, 86.97572322743066]

def y_fit(x,Dx,Cx,Bx,Ex):
    y = Dx*np.sin(Cx*np.arctan(Bx*x - Ex*(Bx*x - np.arctan(Bx*x))))
    return y


       
popt,pcov = curve_fit(f=y_fit, xdata=x, ydata=y)


plt.plot(x, y_fit(x, *popt))
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()

I've tried changing the method and the initial guess, but it has no effect.

I'm able to find a fit using popt,pcov = curve_fit(f=y_fit, xdata=x, ydata=y, maxfev=10000). However, the fit it finds is quite wacky looking: https://i.imgur.com/ZIWc9n0.png

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to give scipy.optimize.curve_fit a good initial guess.
p0 = (150, 2.5, 10, 1)
popt,pcov = curve_fit(f=y_fit, xdata=x, ydata=y, p0=p0)

My process for finding a good initial guess:

Write the equation in Desmos.
Vary the parameters to get an understanding of what each one does.
Go back to Python and plot the target against an initial guess of all 1s.

p0 = (1, 1, ...)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.plot(x, y_fit(x, *p0))
fig.show()


Starting with whichever parameter stands out to me, start varying and rerunning the code until it looks right.
Move onto another parameter, vary, and rerun until it looks right.
Repeat 6 until you have a good initial guess.


How did you find this initial guess? But thank you anyway!

I just edited my answer to explain my process.
